# SQL Error:ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Display itemcode, supplier name and total quantity for the ordered items, whose total quantity ordered is greater than or equal to 100.

```
SELECT QUOT.sname, ORD.Qtyordered,SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED)
from Quotation QUOT
    inner join Orders ORD ON QUOT.QuotationId = ORD.QuotationId
GROUP BY QUOT.sname 
HAVING SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED) >=100 /* No Error */

SELECT QUOT.Itemcode, QUOT.sname, ORD.Qtyordered, SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED)
from Quotation QUOT
    inner join Orders ORD ON QUOT.QuotationId = ORD.QuotationId
GROUP BY QUOT.sname 
HAVING SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED) >=100 /* ERROR not a group by expression */
```

I am beginner in SQL Can anyone help me to write a query.

Comment: add QUOT.Itemcode in your group by

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output for the full answer, off the bat I can tell you that in the GROUP BY clause you must have all columns that are not aggregated in the `SELECT` clause (and are in `SELECT`) and that are not a part of the HAVING clause (and are in `SELECT`)

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 2):

Do not select `ORD.Qtyordered` or `ITEM_CODE` as separate columns.  They are not appropriate in an aggregation query by `sname`:

```
SELECT QUOT.sname, SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED)
from Quotation QUOT inner join
     Orders ORD
     ON QUOT.QuotationId = ORD.QuotationId
GROUP BY QUOT.sname 
HAVING SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED) >= 100 ;
```

If you want the items, you may want `LISTAGG()`.

Or, for the question being asked, include the item in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT QUOT.Itemcode, QUOT.sname, SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED)
from Quotation QUOT inner join
     Orders ORD
     ON QUOT.QuotationId = ORD.QuotationId
GROUP BY QUOT.Itemcode, QUOT.sname 
HAVING SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED) >= 100 ;
```

The limit on `100` is per *item* not item in an order.

Comment: Why do you always beat me? I need to type faster! +1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to adjust the `GROUP BY` of your query to cater for the additional columns you have:

```
SELECT  QUOT.Itemcode,
        QUOT.sname,
        SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED)
  FROM  Quotation QUOT
    INNER JOIN Orders ORD ON QUOT.QuotationId = ORD.QuotationId
  GROUP BY QUOT.Itemcode, QUOT.sname 
  HAVING SUM(ORD.QTYORDERED) >=100
```

When performing aggregate operations with `GROUP BY`, each non-aggregated column should be included in the `GROUP BY` statement.